# What is the "error in [my] SQL syntax" here?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Gotta love when you get descriptive errors like

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax

Can anyone here give me any more of an idea of where I'm going wrong with

```
CREATE TABLE wp_nas_coffees (id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR (100), email VARCHAR (100), company VARCHAR (100), dtime TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, order VARCHAR (20));
```

???

Comment: You need to escape `order` with backticks -- it's a reserved word...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

order is Mysql reserver word

```
CREATE TABLE wp_nas_coffees (
    id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    name VARCHAR (100), 
    email VARCHAR (100), 
    company VARCHAR (100), 
    dtime TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    tbl_order VARCHAR (20)
);
```

See MySQL keywords/reserved words 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html